# Scrollbar only appears for the first element

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, tablelayoutpanel

I have a very simple windows form. As seen from the pictures below, scrollbar appears only for the first item, but once I make the form larger by dragging its border, the scrollbar disappears. What is the reason behind this?

[image: Scrollbar appears only for the first item]

[image: Once I make the form larger by dragging its border, the scrollbar disappears]

The code for the form looks like this:

```
var tlp1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
tlp1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
tlp1.AutoSize = true;
tlp1.BackColor = Color.Bisque;

var tlp2 = new TableLayoutPanel();
tlp2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tlp2.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;

page.Controls.Add(tlp2);
page.Controls.Add(tlp1);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tlp1.Controls.Add(new TextBox()
    {
        Text = string.Format("page1. {0}", i)
    });

    tlp2.Controls.Add(new TextBox()
    {
        Text = string.Format("page2. {0}", i)
    });
}

page.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: You have to set `AutoScroll = true` for the `TableLayoutPanel`'s I believe.

Comment: @Bauss setting as you said puts the scrollbar *inside* the second panel as seen in http://screenpresso.com/=wBCMb

Comment: You could try to compare sizes with the panel and then force a scroll bar on if the sizes of the TLP's are bigger than the actual panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollable area will be the maximum(x + width, y + height) of all controls added to the `ScollableContainer` after the `LayoutEngine` has arranged them.

Since `tlp2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, its ClientRectangle (x, y, width, height) are whatever space is available. In other words, since the beige panel is taking up all the available height, the green panel client height (`ClientRectangle.Height`) is zero. As you increase the height of the main window, more space is available and the extra height is allocated to the green panel. However, when set to `DockStyle.Fill`, the green panel does not contribute to the space needs.

If you set the following:

```
tlp2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
tlp2.AutoSize = true;
```

Then you will have a scrollbar that spans the entire height of both panels. Or another approach is to add the panels to vertical `FlowLayoutPanel`, e.g.

```
class FormTab : Form {

    public FormTab() {
        TabControl tc = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        TabPage page = new TabPage();
        var tlp1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        tlp1.AutoSize = true;
        tlp1.BackColor = Color.Bisque;

        var tlp2 = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp2.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        tlp2.AutoSize = true;
        tlp2.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;

        VFLP p = new VFLP();
        p.SuspendLayout();
        p.Controls.Add(tlp2);
        p.Controls.Add(tlp1);
        page.Controls.Add(p);
        //page.Controls.Add(tlp2);
        //page.Controls.Add(tlp1);

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tlp1.Controls.Add(new TextBox() {
                Text = string.Format("page1. {0}", i)
            });

            tlp2.Controls.Add(new TextBox() {
                Text = string.Format("page2. {0}", i)
            });
        }

        this.DoubleClick += delegate {
            Size s = page.GetPreferredSize(Size.Empty);
            int bp = 1;
        };

        tc.TabPages.Add(page);
        page.AutoScroll = true;
        Controls.Add(tc);
        p.ResumeLayout(true);
    }

    class VFLP : FlowLayoutPanel {

        public VFLP() {
            this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            WrapContents = false;
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            AutoSize = true;
            AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        }

        public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize) {
            Size s = base.GetPreferredSize(proposedSize);
            Size s2 = Size.Empty;
            foreach (Control c in Controls) {
                Size s3 = c.GetPreferredSize(Size.Empty);
                Padding m = c.Margin;
                s2.Height += s3.Height + m.Vertical;
                int w = s3.Width + m.Horizontal;
                if (w > s2.Width)
                    s2.Width = w;
            }

            return s2;
        }
    }
}
```